# Javascript Scope problem when using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

Hey I'm fooling around with google maps API, and at the moment I am struggling to implement something that I would think would be fairly straight forward.

My friend wants to have one of those visitor map things on his site where visitors can add a marker to any point on the map, and with each marker there will be information associated with it. Information such as name, date, message, etc....

Right now I am in the prototyping and learning stage, but I am having trouble associating an `infowindow` with a `marker` object.

```
var map;
var markers = []
function init(){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-44, 140);
        var myOptions = {
                zoom:8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
            markers.push(new marker(event.latLng));
        });
}

function marker(location){
    this.location = location;
    this.mark = new google.maps.Marker({position:this.location, map:map});
    this.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'hi'});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.mark, 'click', function(){
        this.info.open(map, this.mark);
    });
}
```

When I test this code out the markers are placed fine, but when I click on them, instead of displaying the InfoWindow I get this error in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
```

Certainly this is a scope problem, but I can't understand why that should be. Something like this works fine:

```
function test(a){
    this.a = a
    this.b = function(){
        this.a+=1
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're losing scope here:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.mark, 'click', function(){
  this.info.open(map, this.mark);
});
```

Try storing the value of `this` like so:

```
var _self = this;    
google.maps.event.addListener(_self.mark, 'click', function(){
  _self.info.open(map, _self.mark);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but something I've noticed with this solution is that the info box when it appears is all fragmented... Could that be due to its being called in this manner? http://jsfiddle.net/8xHw7/

Comment: Just tried it at your link, seems like it's working fine for me :)

Comment: really? You can't see these lines running through the infowindow? Maybe it's chrome...

Comment: That's funny. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 13.0.782.220 - try resizing your browser, I do see scrollbars if the map area is too small.

Comment: That's just bizarre. Try a different browser or something, looks like not just the infowindow is messed up, but the map as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving what you want to could be by passing this.info as argument to the function which you are associating with the click event and then using 'open' on the parameter passed. This should resolve the issue.

The reason for why this function is not being able to identify this.info is that the function is not being defined as an inner function here.